# How can I have multiple variables in a single form

Tags: php, input

Here is what I have so far:

```
Age: <input type="text" name="age">

   Canoe<input type="radio" name="ck">
        Kayak<input type="radio" name="ck">


<input type="submit" style=" margin-bottom: 30px;">
</form>

You are <?php $_POST["age"];
 if ($_POST["age"]<"11")
 echo "an Atom.";

 elseif ($_POST["age"]<"13")
 echo "a Peewee.";

 elseif ($_POST["age"]<"15")
 echo "a Bantam.";

 elseif ($_POST["age"]<"17")
 echo  "a Midget.";

 elseif ($_POST["age"]<"19")
 echo "a Juvenile.";

 elseif ($_POST["age"]<"21")
 echo "a Junior.";

 elseif ($_POST["age"]<"120")
 echo "a Senior.";

 elseif ($_POST["age"]>"120")
 echo "too old to race";
   ?>
```

I want to be able to include the canoe and kayak radio buttons in this to make the output be like: You are a Peewee canoeist and your opponents this year are:   |  or, you are a midget kayak er. You're opponents this year are:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to echo the CK value into your output? Does this help?

```
Age: <input type="text" name="age">

Canoe<input type="radio" name="ck" value="canoeist">
Kayak<input type="radio" name="ck" value="kayakist">

<input type="submit" style=" margin-bottom: 30px;">
</form>

<?php
        $ck = $_POST["ck"];
?>

You are <?php $_POST["age"];
if ($_POST["age"]<"11")
echo "a $ck Atom.";

elseif ($_POST["age"]<"13")
echo "a $ck Peewee.";

elseif ($_POST["age"]<"15")
echo "a $ck Bantam.";

elseif ($_POST["age"]<"17")
echo  "a $ck Midget.";

elseif ($_POST["age"]<"19")
echo "a $ck Juvenile.";

elseif ($_POST["age"]<"21")
echo "a $ck Junior.";

elseif ($_POST["age"]<"120")
echo "a $ck Senior.";

elseif ($_POST["age"]>"120")
echo "too old to race";
?>
```

The values of the form radio must be canoeist and "kayakist". Just add the `$ck = $_POST['ck'];` and your sentence is like `echo "a $ck Atom.";`

Comment: nice straightforward solution

Answer (score 0):

You should use some variables here.

(I'm not that good at php, but I'll give it a try)

```
Age: <input type="text" name="age">

    Canoe<input type="radio" name="ck" value="canoe"/>
    Kayak<input type="radio" name="ck" value="kayak"/>

<input type="submit" style=" margin-bottom: 30px;">
</form>

$boat = "";
if ($_POST["ck"] == "canoe")
{
    $boat = "canoeist";
} else if ($_POST["ck"] == "kayak")
{
    $boat = "kayak er";
}


$rank = "";
You are <?php $_POST["age"];
 if ($_POST["age"]<"11")
 $rank = "an Atom.";

 elseif ($_POST["age"]<"13")
 $rank = "a Peewee.";

 elseif ($_POST["age"]<"15")
 $rank = "a Bantam.";

 elseif ($_POST["age"]<"17")
 $rank =  "a Midget.";

 elseif ($_POST["age"]<"19")
 $rank = "a Juvenile.";

 elseif ($_POST["age"]<"21")
 $rank = "a Junior.";

 elseif ($_POST["age"]<"120")
 $rank = "a Senior.";

 elseif ($_POST["age"]>"120")
 $rank = "too old to race";

 echo "You are " . $rank . " " . $boat;
   ?>
```